# Как использовать в сниппете переменную из другого сниппета

Tags: modx

У меня наверно совсем простой вопрос по MODX Revo. Но я его почти не знаю, а найти ответ в интернете не получается.
У меня в одном сниппете А хранится массив. Мне надо получать значчения из него в другом сниппете В.
Как это сделать? Условно говоря приинклудить сниппет A к сниппету В?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте сниппет А, кроме прочего внутри вызовите сниппет B и передайте, что нужно:

```
$params = array();
$res = $modx->runSnippet('snippetB', array('array' => $params));
```